# creating MySQL Trigger to insert into second table

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysqladmin

I'm trying to setup a trigger to insert a sum into a second table after insert of the first table.

The tables are:

- First Table Name: likes
- Fields: feedid
- Second Table Name: like_count
- Fields: total, feedid

After insert on `likes` table, I need to check if the `feedid` exists in table `like_count`. If not just insert it with `total` of `1`. If it does exists, I need to update `like_count.total` to increment by one where `likes.feedid = like_count.feedid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQL [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax to simplify the logic of the trigger.

For this to work, `feedid` must be a unique column in table `likes_count` (either it is the primary key of the column, or you need to create a `UNIQUE` constraint on it). Then:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_likes_count
AFTER INSERT ON likes FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO likes_count (feed_id, total) VALUES (NEW.feedid, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total = total + 1;
END;
//
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: @FLcoder: sorry there was a typo, should be `ON DUPLICATE KEY` (no trailing `S`). I fixed the code and added a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have to change the databasename and adept the columns and the insert statement

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `databasename`.`update_feed_count`
AFTER INSERT ON `likes` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE @feedid  VARCHAR(20);
    SELECT feedid INTO @feedid FROM like_count WHERE feedid = NEW.feedid;
    IF @feedid IS NULL OR @feedid = '' THEN
        INSERT INTO like_count (total, feedid) VAKUES (1,NEW.feedid);
    ELSE
        UPDATE like_count lc 
            WHERE `total` = `total` + 1 
            AND NEW.feedid = vc.feedid;
    END IF;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```